# orgmode capture template, how to add entry under org header

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I added a custom template for the capture-mode:

The problem is that the default "Tasks" template is not there anymore.
So I tried to add this:

```
("t" "Tasks" entry
    (file "~/Documents/org/notes.org"))
```

Now, when I press `M-x org-capture`, the "Tasks" option appears in the
template options list.

The default behaviour for the default Tasks template is to add the new
entries under the "* Tasks" headline.

How do I achieve that same feature?

How to add all new entries under a specific header in the .org file?

Thanks in advance for your kind help and time.

Jenia

P.S.

This is how I add the custom template to the org-capture templates list:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '(
    ("c" "Class" entry
       (file "~/Documents/org/class.txt")
       #'org-capture-class)
    ("n" "Exercise session" entry
        (file "~/Documents/org/notes.org"))
    ("t" "Tasks" entry
        (file "~/Documents/org/notes.org"))
))
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear as to the call of the question -- i.e., whether you want to choose any location to insert your new capture; or, whether you want to deal with a specific situation that occurs when the `* Tasks` headline is missing.  Here is a link to a related thread regarding interactively choosing where to refile a new capture:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9005843/2112489

Comment: Here is a link to a thread which has a few examples of creating sub-headings underneath a main heading:  http://superuser.com/a/635294/206164

Comment: nice. cool examples. thanks lawlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell org-mode which headline to file captures to with `(file+headline "file" "Headline")` in the capture template.  So your example becomes

```
("t" "Tasks" entry
    (file+headline "~/Documents/org/notes.org" "Tasks"))
```