# How can I capture a note under a Interactively enter headline

Tags: org-mode, capture

I am using a capture template from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005843/interactively-enter-headline-under-which-to-place-an-entry-using-capture). The script lets me choose under which headline I would like to file my new note. I want to use this script so that I can dynamicly choose under witch header to file my new note.

Instead of using `entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "Movies")` where the headers are pre defined

Unfortunately this script is not working properly. It does not write it under the correct header, but creates a new header with this result

```
* inbox.org/Movies
*  Watch new james bond movie
<2020-07-12 Sun 17:03:28>
```

Instead of creating a header in the inbox.org file under

```
* Movies
**  Watch new james bond movie
<2020-07-12 Sun 17:03:28>
```

```
(setq org-capture-templates  
(append org-capture-templates
     (quote (

                ("t" "add task")
    
("to" "other" 
entry (file+function "~/org/gtd.org" org-ask-location)
    "\n\n** %?\n<%<%Y-%m-%d %a %T>>"
    :empty-lines 1)


               )
        )
     )
)



(defun org-ask-location ()
  (let* ((org-refile-targets '((nil :maxlevel . 9)))
         (hd (condition-case nil
                 (car (org-refile-get-location "Headline" nil t))
               (error (car org-refile-history)))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (outline-next-heading)
    (if (re-search-forward
         (format org-complex-heading-regexp-format (regexp-quote hd))
         nil t)
        (goto-char (point-at-bol))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (or (bolp) (insert "\n\n"))
      (insert "* " hd "\n\n")))
    (end-of-line))
```

Comment: What do you expect should happen?

Comment: Is it misbehaving only when you specify the first headline in the file?

Comment: _I have edit the post._ It is misbehaving with every headline that i choose
I wand to file new notes under the correct header. I understand that it is also possible with org refile, now I have temporary solved it with tags to organize #movies #books ect

Comment: There are some problems: if the first heading is at the beginning of the file it will be skipped - add an empty line at the top of the file to work around this problem. And the header ("Movies" in your example) must (probably: I haven't checked)  exist in the file already. But given this, the function seems to work fine for me.

Comment: How has this developed? Did youmanage to make it work? I am having exactly the same issue.